# Binding ObservableCollectiron to USER DataGrid in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have Observable collection which contains header names as Name, Address, Departmet.
i want to Display above observable collection with Different names like Employee Name, Location and Group

can someone help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the Header of each Column by yourself:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourObservableCollection}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DaraGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```